# Sampling from tensorflow Dataset into same tensor multiple times per single session.run() call

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Consider the following example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(4).reshape(4, 1) + (np.arange(3) / 10).reshape(1, 3)

batch = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X) \
        .batch(2).make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

def foo(x):
    return x + 1

tensor = foo(batch)
```

Now, I'm looking for a way to be able to sample `tensor` multiple times per single `session.run()` call, i.e.:

```py
def bar(x):
    return x - 1

result1 = bar(tensor)
with tf.control_dependencies([result1]):
    op = <create operation to sample from dataset into `tensor` again>
    with tf.control_dependencies([op]):
        result2 = bar(tensor)

sess = tf.Session()
print(*sess.run([result1, result2]), sep='\n\n')
```

which should output:

```
[[0.  0.1 0.2]
 [1.  1.1 1.2]]

[[2.  2.1 2.2]
 [3.  3.1 3.2]]
```

Is that even possible? I know one can call `get_next()` multiple times to get multiple dataset samples in **different** tensor objects, but can one sample into the **same** tensor object?

For me the use case is such that the `foo` and `bar` parts of this code are separated, and the `foo` part doesn't know how many times the samples will be needed per run.

P.S.
I'm using tf 1.12. 1.13 is an option too, but not tf 2 though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

A couple of insights on what you've tried so far:

1. You can use the dataset iterator returned from `make_one_shot_iterator()` each time you need a new value from the dataset
2. You can make your own function that is part of the tf graph to pass the result through `foo()`

Something like this give the output you want (as I understand it)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(4).reshape(4, 1) + (np.arange(3) / 10).reshape(1, 3)

iterator = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X) \
        .batch(2).make_one_shot_iterator()

def foo(x):
    return x + 1

def get_tensor():
  return foo(iterator.get_next())

tensor = get_tensor()

def bar(x):
    return x - 1

result1 = bar(tensor)
with tf.control_dependencies([result1]):
    op = get_tensor()
    with tf.control_dependencies([op]):
        result2 = bar(op)

sess = tf.Session()
print(*sess.run([result1, result2]), sep='\n\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not sampling into the **same tensor object**, this is creating a new tensor. Initially I wanted to avoid that, but now that I think of it, there's probably no good reason to why I want to avoid that.

I'm still curious on whether it's possible to resample to the same tensor though.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding - I'm not sure what you mean by 'sampling into' the same tensor object (i mistook this as "getting the next sample tensor from the same dataset object"). You can certainly reuse `tensor` as many times as you want to as the input for subsequent operations but I suspect that's not what you mean? A tensor is nothing more than a (structured) set of numbers. You can assign a new tensor to the variable name, you can change the values with `tf.assign` and you can pass a tensor as input to as many downstream ops as you like but it sounds like you have something else in mind?

Comment: Well, what I meant was the following. If I have a tensor which holds a sample/batch from a dataset, and then I have a number of subsequent operations on that tensor, I wanted to be able to reuse these exact operations on another sample/batch from that dataset without building a duplicate branch of operations in the graph.